# How to add a control to the Non client area of a custom form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, custom-controls

I'm developing a custom form that provides more options to customize the appearance of the form.

For that I have derived the class from **System.Windows.Forms.Form** class and overridden the **WndProc(ref Message m)** method.

I have processed the required window messages (WM_NCPAINT, WM_NCCALCSIZE, etc) to customize the form.

Now I have to provide the support for adding a control to the TitleBar of my custom form. (That is in the non client area of the form).

The user could able to add any control(like Label, Button) to the title bar of the form.

Controls.Add() method will add the control within the client area of the form.

Is there any possibilities to add controls to the non client area of the form?

Please share your valuable ideas on this.

Regards,

Mohanram.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have got answer for this question. Please refer the below link for the answer.
This may help others. It works for me.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/349d5d86-3b59-4116-9c5b-f5240f1bed4d/how-to-add-a-control-to-the-non-client-area-of-a-custom-form?forum=csharpgeneral&prof=required
Thanks,

Mohanram

Comment: Link-only answers are not welcomed. Consider to edit enough details into this answer to make it sufficient without having to go somewhere else.